# If question A is closed as a dupe of question B, it should bump B to the front page

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, question-lists

Since questions that are closed as duplicates may have answers, I think it would be great if:

- the target (non closed) question gained a link to the dupe (ideally in a "duplicates" section with an indication of how many answers it has)
- the target (non closed) question was bumped to the front page

I believe the first request is sort of in place on meta where we have two way "linked" relationship - this is not the same as a Duplicates section however.

The second I haven't seen mentioned before and I think it would be good.

What will happen to the bumped B when it hits the front page?

- it may be edited. I see a number of "B"s in the review queue that are really crappy as questions. Yes, they ask the same thing as the "A" I am reviewing, but they are full of meta talk, badly formatted etc. Some days I use the history link in the review queue to go make the "B" better, some days I don't. If B was bumped, other people might take a look at it and clean it up if it's starting to become an important repository
- it may gain another answer. Apparently this is a problem that recurs and that many people face. Let's see if it has all the answers it needs. It's possible B has a perfect answer, but then again whoever asked A didn't come across B and has a problem to be solved. Like any edit to B, it may lead more people to read it and perhaps to answer it.
- it may gain views, or votes. It deserves those, since it was written well enough to attract at least one reasonable answer and it's now serving as a dupe-target

Comment: What action(s) would you expect people to take on dup target as a result of another question being marked as a duplicate of it?  After all, that's the point of indicating "activity" on a question, so the actions can be reviewed by others.  What actions do you see needing to be taken here?

Comment: There will be a link in the question to direct people to question B.

Comment: If the dup target doesn't have an answer that answers the question it shouldn't be used as a dup target in the first place.  If it is, then the closing of the other question is a problem, so it's the activity of the closed question that's relevant.

Comment: The close voters may feel it's an answer. Doesn't mean everyone who reads it agrees. Just as editing to add more info may prompt more answers, so saying "here's another way to word this question" may prompt more answers.

Comment: @KateGregory Those are all reasons to bump the closed question, not the target.  If others feel that it isn't answered by the duplicate bumping the target isn't the solution, it's getting views to the closed question.  If someone only sees the dup target because it was bumped they aren't seeing the new wording, only the old one.  The dup target *already* gets renewed attention as a result of the proposed or actual duplicate closure, which covers all of the cases that you've described so far.

Comment: Imagine A is "how do I Foo with Bar" and B is "how do I use Bar to Foo?" They are clearly dupes. There are some answers to B but not great ones. People are still asking how to do it. So it needs answers. Bumping A won't help, it's closed. Bumping B might help.

Comment: Might make people start gaming the system to get their question to the top.

Comment: @ChrisChambers It's far easier to edit B (which bumps it) than to go find an A which might be a dupe of it and vote/flag to close it then get 4 or 5 other people to agree with you all in the hope of bumping B.

Comment: @ChrisChambers They can already do that easily enough by just doing little edits on their question.